# Present perfect or past simple : example

Tags: past-tense

Which tense should I use in this sentence ?

**Context:** The kitchen is dirty and I want to ask to my friend if it's because of him.

> Is it you who have cooked in the kitchen?
>   Is it you who cooked in the kitchen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Past Tense (for both):

> **Was** it you who cooked in the kitchen?

or Present Tense (for both, the second it Present Perfect):

> Is it you who **has** cooked in the kitchen?

Or simpler, just ask: *Did you cook and made such a mess in the kitchen?*

Answer (score 0):

Coming from an English person, the first one doesn't make much sense as it is, I believe you would change it to

> Is it you who **has** cooked in the kitchen?

The second one is okay too, as it means the exact same thing. The `has` is optional in this case. However, although an English speaker would know what you are talking about, there are still better ways of asking the question.

Ideally, to fit in with your format, you should probably be asking:

> Is it you who has been cooking in the kitchen?

Or even better:

> Have you been cooking in the kitchen?